# Enter next line by verifying if string length has reached the specified number

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I want to create a *condition* in **PHP** to check whether the length of the string has reached the specified value and if the condition is true then show rest of the characters on the next line. The string is passed from a form using *POST* method.

Comment: When you say "next line" do you mean in the HTML sense (i.e. insert a <br /> or similar or just go to next line in output source?

Comment: If <br/> will do the work then yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the [wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function?

Answer (score 1):

considering the specific length is 10

```
 if(strlen($_POST['str']) > 10)
    echo "\n". substr($_POST['str'],10);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$max_length = 100;
$string = 'mystring'; // or whatever 

if(strlen($string) > $max_length){
    $sub_str = substr($string, $max_length);
}
```

echo `$sub_str` on a new line if `$sub_str` is set.

Comment: in your example, if the `$max_length` is 100, the condition will always be `FALSE`

Comment: @sweettea that is only if the string is less. If the string would be more then 100 char it would be true.

Comment: when you provide an example, it should work on its own, dont u think :)

Comment: @sweettea it does work. It correctly checks the length and only if true breaks a line. The OP's question takes into account the possibility of it returning false!

Comment: wordwrap() function works best for my query. Thanx for your help